# How do I store a parameter in Search so I can retrieve it when showing results? (Magento)

Tags: php, parameters, magento, session-variables

I need to search for some products' custom options (set in Manage Products|Edit Product|Custom Options), the only way I've found is manually filtering the results returned by Magento's search function. The question is: How do I store the info I need, so I can remove products not matching my criteria --once Magento returns its results?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `Mage::registry` approach which stores data per request. To store it:

```
if(!Mage::registry('custom_search_critera')){  //check not already set
   Mage::register('custom_search_critera', $values);
}
```

To retrieve from another object or function:

```
$values = Mage::registry('custom_search_critera');
```

Cheers,
JD

Answer (score 1):

In the session of course :) This is the first thing that comes to me and I guess it is the best approach.

Answer (score 0):

For data that you need to persist, use Magento sessions:

```
Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->setXXX( 'SomeData' );
Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getXXX();
```

(where XXX is some identifier, eg setSomeVeryImportantInfo)

I've also found `'customer/session'` and `'admin/session'`.